# Slider con texto en JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Tengo un `Slider` con los meses del año:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero que se muestre con texto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué tengo que hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas utilizar `setLabelFormatter` sobre el `Slider`.

Aquí tienes el código:

```
sliderMeses.setSnapToTicks(true);
sliderMeses.setLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Double>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(Double n) {
        switch (n.intValue()) {
            case 1:
                return "ene";
            case 2:
                return "feb";
            case 3:
                return "mar";
            case 4:
                return "abr";
            case 5:
                return "may";
            case 6:
                return "jun";
            case 7:
                return "jul";
            case 8:
                return "ago";
            case 9:
                return "sep";
            case 10:
                return "oct";
            case 11:
                return "nov";
            case 12:
                return "dic";
            default:
                return "???";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Double fromString(String s) {
        switch (s) {
            case "ene":
                return 0d;
            case "feb":
                return 1d;
            case "mar":
                return 2d;
            case "abr":
                return 3d;                    
            case "may":
                return 4d;
            case "jun":
                return 5d;
            case "jul":
                return 6d;
            case "ago":
                return 7d;
            case "sep":
                return 8d;
            case "oct":
                return 9d;
            case "nov":
                return 10d;
            case "dic":
                return 11d;
            default:
                return -1d;
        }
    }
});
```